# Meteor collection Method calls waiting, or how to implement batch DB operation efficiently

Tags: meteor

We are working on a highly interactive design tool using Meteor. Meteor has done a great job for us since we migrated to Meteor last year. It has simplified our development dramatically. But recently we found a big performance issue in our app.

After investigating deeply and I found out that it's due to how we update the database. Our app is a quite complicated design tool, and it has lot of data for each user project. And when user make a change to the design, it will run the logic, then create, update and remove hundreds even thousands of small objects in the data collections. As collection operations has stub method in the client side, the UI is updated very fast and it feels very performant.  But on the server side, it can be slowed down dramatically. As the hundreds of DB operations generate method calls and it only run one by one. The server process can take 100% CPU usage for a few seconds even only one user make a small change. I used Kadira to profile the server and found out that some methods spend 99% of the time waiting.

One of the solution is batch DB operations, but meteor doesn't support it. Any idea on how to implement such a solution? or how to circumvent the lots-of-db-operation problem generally? I'm kind of stuck on this issue and any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor exposes the Node Mongodb driver connection in MongoInternals.  That driver [supports bulk inserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/).

So the below should work:

```
var meteorCol = new Meteor.Collection( 'yourCollection' );
meteorCol.remove({});
console.log( 'Count :', meteorCol.find().count());  
var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
var mongoCol = db.collection( 'yourCollection' );

//make a synchronous function so the insert can be checked
var mongoInsert = Meteor._wrapAsync( mongoCol.insert ).bind( mongoCol );

//batch insert
mongoInsert([{hello:'world_safe1'}
  , {hello:'world_safe2'}]
  , {w:1}
);

console.log( 'Count :', meteorCol.find().count());
```

Code is running in [Meteor Pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/c73i7NC7KuwtDeXq7) if you want to play with it.

Just doing the batch inserts may not completely avoid performance problems according to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/Y547Hh2z39Y/0TYVg0lraBIJ).

Comment: I started that discussion. No, bulk inserts won't fix the problem because the issue is with how the oplog affects CPU usage, which scales with the number of connected users times the number of database operations. This needs to be fixed architecturally in Meteor. In my app, I have a temporary workaround by minimizing the number of db operations done while lots of clients are connected.

Comment: Thanks. But I think my app need to have the client side updated so the UI can update reactively.  So I realized a bulk operation API may not fix the problem. Just as Andrew said. Now I have an idea to change the data structure. Instead of storing those different data in separate collections and model them as in a relational database, I will try to use a big nested document to model the problem so that I can reduce hundreds of small db operations into only ONE bigger db update operation. I think this should work. I will change my app and report the result later here.

Comment: I don't think your wait time is caused by the oplog cpu usage issue.  It sounds more like you have implemented a series of db calls from the client rather than writing one method call to manage the full series of operations.  Wait time in Kadira is all related to a specific client's queue of methods and initial publishes and it lists them by name.  Fixing the wait time may still leave the slow cpu problem Andrew describes but it should still be fixed.  The batch method I wrote is reactive, can have a stub for latency comp, and is only offered because that is what your question requests.